# "du" question; "à le + [noun event]" as meaning "at the [noun event]"?

Tags: traduction, constructions, à

The following was an advertisement that I saw earlier today at the post office:

> Obtenez GRATUITEMENT le service de réacheminement **du** courrier
>   pendant un mois **à l'achat** d'un abonnement de 12 mois.
>
> Get one FREE month of Mail Forwarding when purchasing 12 months of
>   service.

1.

`le service de réacheminement *du* courrier` = "Mail Forwarding [Service]".

I do not know why it is ***du*** instead of *de*.

My understanding is that "de" is used to describe the kind or use of a noun:

- "la chaise de chien" = "the dog chair"
  (ie, "dog" is a kind of adjective that describes the specific kind of chair. it's not all chairs in existence that you're talking about -- it's those that are "dog" chairs).

and that "de + le/la/les (or de + mon/ma/mes etc)" is used to describe possession:

- "la chaise du chien" = "the dog's chair"
- "la chaise de mon chien" = "my dog's chair" (ie, the chair belonging to my dog).

--

For example, the "de" in "le service de [mail forwarding]" makes sense. It's not every kind of service in existence that I'm talking about. It's the *mail forwarding* services I'm talking about; *mail forwarding* is a kind of adjective to "service".

In this way, it sounds like "Mail Forwarding" should be ***de*** (ie, "réacheminement de corrier"), because "Mail" is a kind of adjective that describes "Forwarding".

**Question 1:** Why is it "réacheminement ***du*** courrier", instead of *de*?

2.

The English group-of-words "when purchasing 12 months of service" is translated with "**à l'achat** d'un abonnement de 12 mouis".

This is a sentence construction that I am unfamiliar with. I am trying to understand it.

I understand that "l'achat" means "the purchase". I'm unfamiliar with the construction 'à + [noun that describes some event *(such as purchasing something)*]" to mean "at the time [noun] happened".

**Question 2a:** Can you give me more examples of this construction?
**Question 2b:** Can you give me a website that explains this usage of **à** ?
**Question 2c:** Are there other ways of translating "when purchasing 12 months of service", such as "quand vous achetez un abonnement de 12 mois" or "en achetant un abonnement de 12 mois"?

**Question 3:** Would the sentence still be correct if we replaced "pendant" with "de"?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1 :**

---

I think that you are right. Saying **de** would not be grammatically wrong. But I think **du** is used because the mails that are forwarded are not just any mails. For example, in `un service de réacheminement de courrier` here the **de** would be prefered because it's indifinite.

**Question 2 :**

---

Some examples :

> [...] des hommes mûrs pleuraient à la vue du drapeau étoilé soutenu par tout le corps de ballet noyé sous les clartés des projecteurs. (H. G. Wells, La Guerre dans les airs)
>
> Il recevra un cadeau à l'obtention de son diplôme.

I did not find any website but I can tell you that **à** is used as a `complément circonstanciel de temps`. Which means that it decribes the moment, here following on an action/event. So you could remplace it by :

> Lors de l'achat d'un abonnement de 12 mois
>
> Suite à l'achat d'un abonnement de 12 mois
>
> Après avoir acheté un abonnement de 12 mois

As you suggested, it can also be replaced by :

> Quand vous achetez d'un abonnement de 12 mois
>
> en achetant un abonnement de 12 mois

**Question 3 :**

---

No. But Yes if the sentence was :

> Obtenez GRATUITEMENT un service de réacheminement de courrier **d'un** mois à l'achat d'un abonnement de 12 mois.

Comment: i'm a little bit unclear on Question 1. what is the difference in meaning between de and du? when using " du", what exactly is the "le courriel" being referred to (in some definite way) -- i haven't signed up for the service yet! Why would `*un* service de réacheminement *de* courrier` be more preferred than `*un* service *du* réacheminement de courrier`?